# Performing t-test on individual rows

Tags: r, statistics, t-test

hoping for a bit of help with something that should (hopefully) be easy enough for those with the knowledge.

I am working with a dataset with 111 columns and 300 rows. The first 70 columns are control data, columns 71-111 contain data on people with diabetes. I have performed the following t-test on the first row:

```
row1 <- data[1:1,]

control_cols <- c(1:70)
control <- row1[control_cols]

diabetes_cols <- c(71:111)
diabetes <- row1[diabetes_cols]

t.test(control, diabetes, mu=0, paired = F, conf.level=0.95)
```

Is there a way than I can use the apply function to automate this to perform the t-test on each row, so that I can see the p-values of each row individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` to execute the t-test for each row, and assign the result to a new column in `data`

```
data["pvalue"] = apply(data,1,function(r) t.test(r[1:70], r[71:111])$p.value)
```